# Continuous function composed with itself is equal to propagation of a differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, function-and-relation-composition

This question has been bugging me for a while. It was given as the last question of a first year undergrad analysis exam and so should be solvable with little machinery,
yet it seems to point straight at ODEs which have yet to be covered. Here is the question:

> Let $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded $\mathscr{C}^1$ function and $\left(f_t:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\right)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ a family of continuous functions with $f_0(x)=x$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f_{t+h}(x)-f_t(x)}{h}=F(f_t(x))$$ Show that there exists a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1 = g\circ g$.

I have attempted this with a classmate and we've come to various levels of understanding of the question, but the required conclusion keeps escaping us. Our main issues with the question are that we have very little understanding on continuous functions composed with themselves, and additionally we haven't managed to use the $\mathscr{C}^1$ and boundedness condition on $F$.

Note that the question also states that we are allowed to assume that the family of functions $(f_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is uniquely determined by the given conditions: this again points to the domain of differential equations, which ideally we should not need to refer to in order to solve this.

Comment: With the uniqueness assumption, you just need to show that the family $(f_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ defines a flow, i.e., $f_{t+s}(x)=f_t(f_s(x))$. Then, an answer could be simply $g:=f_{1/2}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @AugustoSantos huh okay I don't think I would've been able to think of that... How did you reach this conclusion, I'm having trouble seeing how $F$ factors into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and define $h_t(x)\overset{\Delta}=f_{t+s}(x)$. Then, it is trivial to conclude that $\frac{d}{dt} h_t(x)=F(h_t(x))$. Further, define $w_t(x)=f_t(f_s(x))$. Then, again, it is trivial to show that $\frac{d}{dt}w_t(x)=F(w_t(x))$. From the referred uniqueness, $\left(w_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}=\left(h_t\right)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$. In other words, $f_{t+s}(x)=f_t(f_s(x))$ for any $x$ and now choose $g=f_{\frac{1}{2}}$ so that $g\circ g= f_{1/2}\circ f_{1/2}=f_1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Do you think you could explain why boundedness and continuity of the F' is required in the hypotheses, or are they not?

Comment: @LittleNarwhal: $F$ being bounded and continuous implies the existence of a family $\left(f_t(x)\right)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ for each $x$; $F$ being $\mathcal{C}^1$ implies that the family $\left(f_t(x)\right)_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is unique for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$. In other words, this was a sufficient condition to grant the existence and uniqueness of the family given $x$. But, were you supposed to prove this as well?

Comment: No we were not since the question said we were allowed to assume that these facts were true, so the question does kinda throw you off in trying to figure out what boundedness and continuity are for... Thank you very much for your answers i can rest easy knowing the answer now, and that it wasn't at all an unreasonable question to ask since I should've been able to come up with an answer like this.